# Solving nonlinear ODE in boundary layer of matched asymptotic expansion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In finding a matched asymptotic expansion for the equation: $$f_{xx} - \frac{1}{2x^{3/2}}\epsilon f f_x = 0, \ \ f(0)=1, \ \ f(1)=0$$

I am having problems with finding the solution in the boundary layer: setting $\xi = x \epsilon^{-\alpha}$, we get:
$$\epsilon^{-2\alpha} f_{\xi \xi}- \frac{1}{2 \xi^{3/2}}\epsilon^{1-\frac{5}{2}\alpha} ff_{\xi} =0$$
So balacing terms gives: $-2\alpha = 1-\frac{5}{2}\alpha$ and so $\alpha =2$. So the boundary layer is at $x=O(\epsilon^2)$. I know from a previous problem that the asymptotic solution should have just the orders $1, \epsilon^2$. Then, setting $Y(\xi)$ for the inner solution, and expanding as $Y \approx Y_0 + \epsilon^2 Y_1$ into the equation I get

$$ (Y_{0\xi\xi} + \epsilon^2 Y_{1\xi\xi}) - \frac{(Y_0 + \epsilon^2 Y_1)(Y_{0\xi} + \epsilon^2 Y_{1\xi})}{\xi^{3/2}} = 0$$

Which gives the equation for $O(1):Y_{0\xi\xi} - \frac{Y_0Y_{0\xi}}{\xi^{3/2}} = 0$ and for $O(\epsilon^2): Y_{1\xi\xi} - \frac{Y_0Y_{1\xi} + Y_1Y_0\xi}{\xi^{3/2}} = 0$. Can anyone help me with solving these two equations for $Y_0$ and $Y_1$?

Answer (score 0):

There is no boundary layer, what you get is a simple perturbation series $f=f_0+ϵf_1+ϵ^2f_2+...$ starting with
$$
f_0=1-x
$$
and
$$
f_1''=\frac{f_0f_0'}{2x^{3/2}}=\frac{x^{-1/2}}2-\frac{x^{-3/2}}2
\\~\\\implies f_1 = \tfrac23x^{3/2}-\tfrac83x+2x^{1/2}=(2-\tfrac23x^{1/2})x^{1/2}(1-x^{1/2})
$$
Numerical experiments confirm that nothing more happens.